What’s the reason for choosing $a^n$ for solving second order linear recurrence relations?
I understand that in solving second-order linear recurrence relations like:
$X_n = c_1 X_{n-1} + c_2 X_{n-2}$,
we often assume the solution is of the form  $a^n$, leading to a characteristic equation whose roots give the independent solutions. My specific question is:
Why is  $a^n$ chosen as the form for the solution?
How does this choice guarantee that any valid sequence (with different initial values) can be represented as a linear combination of the independent solutions derived from the characteristic equation?
I’m particularly interested in understanding the deeper reasoning behind why  $a^n$ works for all possible sequences that follow a specified recursion rule, that is second order. There should be some weird property of $a^n$ I can’t see such that it models a second order linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients.
Given I only have an elementary knowledge of math, and making use of it, maybe there is some way to prove that $a^n$ is suitable through using the log function? Maybe not.

I would presume a similar reason that the ansatz $e^x$ is used for differential equations like $y'' = c_1 y' + c_2 y.$

When I teach calculus, I often show students Binet's formula (for the Fibonacci sequence).  The first step is to plot $n$ on the horizontal axis, and $F_n$ on the vertical axis.  The graph "looks" roughly exponential so it is reasonable to guess that a closed form for $F_n$ ought to be exponential.  The only question, then is, "What is the base?"

Cf. Wikipedia; note that for first-order $a^n$ seems obvious

@SeanRoberson My view of why $e^x$ is chosen for differential equation is rather shallow but I would assume it’s how it’s derivatives are linearly dependent and so linear combinations of the derivatives and the solution itself would equal whatever it is you want to equal(0 or not) but I’m not quite sure how $a^n$ is useful here. But then again, I don’t know much

If you are asking how we know that the only possible solutions are linear combinations of some set of $a_i^n$, then this is a question (eventually) about linear algebra and finding a basis for some space (the kind of recurrence relation in the question is linear, so linear combinations of solutions are also solutions; the problem can be rephrased as an eigenvalue problem, and the whole solution space can be described in terms of those eigenvalues).  The argument is not super-duper elementary, so if this is the first time you've seen this kind of thing, it might go over your head.

On the other hand, if the question is "Why would someone even think to try linear combinations of $a_i^n$?", then my previous comment gets at that.  These kinds of recurrence relations typically "look" like exponential functions.  So take a guess that the solution should be exponential, and see where it gets you.

@XanderHenderson I see, maybe at my level I should just accept this as a fact, though unsettling. I was wishing for some intuitive and elementary proof but looks like it may require even higher level math.

I’ll just leave the post up in case someone has a creative and weird proof.

Note that $a^n$ solves $X_n=aX_{n-1}$

Note that there are some exceptional cases where exponential functions don't generate all solutions, such as $X_n = 6 X_{n-1} - 9 X_{n-2}$ - where the general solution is linear combinations of $3^n$ and $n \cdot 3^n$.

There is the path of solving for a generating function, then expanding that generating function by partial fractions.  (Looks similar to solving second-order constant coefficient differential equations using the Laplace transform.)  But I'm not sure whether that would count as a reasonable answer to the question as asked.

It works and you can prove it. For the rigourous derivation, you can use generating functions of linear algebra

To expand on @XanderHenderson's statement: Even without the theoretic side, if you just know about diagonalization of matrices, we can show a weaker version of the proof that works for already most of the difference equations

If you don't have access to tools like generating functions or the like, then the inspiration behind choosing an exponential function might start from noticing that for the first-order equation $X_n = c X_{n-1}$, it's already pretty clear that the solution is $X_n = A c^n$ - you can get there from a bit of observation, plus induction to formally prove it.
From there, looking at a second-order equation like $X_n = c_1 X_{n-1} + c_2 X_{n-2}$, you might think "wouldn't it be nice if the solution to this one was just exponential too?", and that's what leads you to trying it. So you put in $X_n = A r^n$ as a candidate solution, and you get:
$$\begin{eqnarray} A r^n & = & c_1 A r^{n-1} + c_2 A r^{n-2} \\
r^n - c_1 r^{n-1} - c_2 r^{n-2} & = & 0 \\
r^2 - c_1 r - c_2 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}$$
and that's just a quadratic in $r$ so you can solve it and you find that you now have two solutions corresponding to the two possible values of $r$. In particular, if $X_0 = A$ and $X_1 = A r$ for either of the solutions to this quadratic, then $X_n = A r^n$ is the solution to this equation. Meaning that for two specific sets of starting conditions we have solved the equation. (For example, if our equation were $X_n = 5 X_{n-1} - 6 X_{n-2}$ then notice that the starting conditions $(X_0, X_1) = (1, 2)$ lead to $X_n = 2^n$ as the solution, while $(X_0, X_1) = (1, 3)$ lead to $X_n = 3^n$.)
From there, we notice that these equations satisfy superposition - meaning that if I have two sequences $X_n$ and $Y_n$ that each individually satisfy the equation, then their sum $X_n + Y_n$ is also a solution. So then if we set the two values of $r$ to be $r_1$ and $r_2$, we now know that any sequence of the form $A r_1^n + B r_2^n$ is a solution to our equation.
The last thing we need to do is to prove that this describes all of the solutions. We know that a solution will be uniquely defined by its values of $X_0$ and $X_1$ (because that gives us $X_2$, from which we get $X_3$, and so on), and we notice that if we substitute those into our candidate solution we get:
$$\begin{eqnarray} X_0 & = & A r_1^0 + B r_2^0 \\
& = & A + B \\
X_1 & = & A r_1^1 + B r_2^1 \\
& = & A r_1 + B r_2
\end{eqnarray}$$
meaning that we have a pair of linear equations in two unknowns ($A$ and $B$) that we can solve. From this, we can see that choosing this particular pair of $A$ and $B$ gives us a formula that satisfies the required initial conditions, which then means that it must be the actual solution.
From this point, extending to higher dimensions is pretty clear - testing the ansatz solution $X = A r^n$ gives a polynomial in $r$, which leads to being able to write a general solution as sums of exponentials of the roots of that polynomial, and the equations you get from a choice of initial conditions uniquely defines the coefficients.
Things get a bit uglier if the polynomial has repeated roots, since that leads to situations where you don't actually have a way to uniquely determine the coefficients, and proving that this introduces an extra term into the solution is a bit trickier. It also gets a little weird if your polynomial has complex roots but your sequence has real solutions, but when you work through the algebra you'll find that all the imaginary parts cancel out.

I think probably the best explanation of the solution $a^n$ for the second-order recurrence relation is the following:
The key point is to notice that we have a family of linear recurrence relations, and the second-order linear recurrence relations have an easier sibling, namely first order recurrence relations! These have the form $x_n= c_1x_{n-1}$, and by induction we immediately see that the relation has the unique solution $x_n = c_1^n x_0$ once the initial term $x_0$ is given. The space of solutions of a first-order recurrence relation is one-dimensional.
To study higher-order recurrence relations, it helps to be a bit more scientific in our approach: Let us define a "shift" operator $S$ on the space of sequences $(x_n)$, where $S(x_n) = (x_{n-1})$, that is $S(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots) = (0,x_0,x_1,\ldots)$. Then a first-order recurrence relation is an equation of the form
$$
c_1 S((x_n))=(x_n), \iff (c_1S-I)((x_n)) = 0 \iff (S-c_1^{-1}I)((x_n))=0
$$
thus, if you know any linear algebra, solving the first order recurrence relation finds the eigenvalues of the linear operator $S$.
A second-order recurrence relation takes the form
$$
c_2S^2((x_n))+c_1S((x_n)) -(x_n) = 0 \quad \text{ or }\quad (c_2S^2+c_1S-I)((x_n))=0
$$
Case 1: the polynomial $p(t) =c_2t^2+ c_1t+1$ has distinct roots.
To make things more explicit, let's take a specific example. Say our recurrence is
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
(6S^2-5S+I)((x_n))=0
$$
Then notice that $(6S^2-5S+I) = (3S-I)(2S-I)=(2S-I)(3S-I)$. Because the two terms $(3S-I)$ and $(2S-I)$ commute, any solution of either first-order recurrence will be a solution of $(\dagger)$, thus we immediately see that $a_0(3^{n}) + b_0 (2^{n})$ is a two-parameter family of solutions to our second order recurrence. But if we are given $x_0$ and $x_1$, then by induction, the recurrence relation $(\dagger)$ determines $x_n$ for all $n \geq 2$. It follows that the space of solutions to $(\dagger)$ is at most two dimensional, and hence we have found the general solution to the recurrence $(\dagger)$.
Now given a general second order recurrence relation $(c_2S^2+c_1S-I)$ the same strategy will tell us that the general solution is $a_0(\lambda_1^{-n}) + b_0(\lambda_2^{-n})$, where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the roots of the quadratic polynomial $q(t)=c_2t^2+c_1t-1$, provided that $q$ has distinct roots! When $q$ has a repeated root, the argument above fails, and we must find another approach.
Case 2: the polynomial $q(t) = c_2t^2+c_1t+1$ has a repeated root.
In this case we may assume that $q(t)=(c_1t-1)^2$. A useful simplification in this case is to note that if $(x_n)$ satisfies $(c_1S-I)^2((x_n))=0$, then if we set $(y_n) = (c_1^{-n}x_n)$ so that $x_n = c_1^n y_n$, it is easy to check that $(S-I)^2(y_n)=0$ -- that is, we can reduce to the case where $c_1=1$. But now $(S-I)^2((x_n))=0$ implies that if $(z_n) = (S-I)((x_n))$ then $(S-I)((z_n))=0$, and we have already seen that this recurrence has solutions $(1^n x_0)$ (that is, the space of constant sequences). Thus it remains to solve the recurrence relation $(S-I)((x_n)) = a_0(1^n)$, that is $x_{n-1}-x_n = a$ for all $n\geq 1$. But now it is easy to see by induction that $x_n = x_0-na$, and putting everything together, we find that the general solution to the second order recurrence $(c_1S-I)^2((x_n))=0$ is given by
$$
(x_n) = (a_0+a_1 n)(c_1^n), \quad \text{where } a_0,a_1 \text{ are arbitrary constants}.
$$
Addendum: It may be useful to note that you can use exactly the same strategy to study constant coefficient linear differential equations. If we write $D$ for $\frac{d}{dt}$, then the first order equation is usually written as $(D-\lambda)(f)=0$, and it has a $1$-dimensional space of solutions $\{Ce^{\lambda t}\mid C \text{ a constant}\}$. Second order equations are of the form $(D^2+c_1D +c_0I)(f)=0$, and if the associated quadratic $t^2+c_1t+c_0$ has distinct roots $r_1,r_2$, then the second order equation has solution space $\{c_1e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t}: c_1,c_2 \text{ constants}\}$. (To see that the space is $2$-dimensional, rather than at least two dimensional, requires a little more work in this context than it did in the recurrence relation one). Finally if the quadratic has a repeated root, one can reduce to the case where the polynomial is simply $t^2$, and the solutions to $D^2(f)=0$ are just the polynomials of degree at most $1$.

It was very helpful. Thanks for the detailed reply.
